# Laravel: Regex to strip part of a url

Tags: php, regex, laravel

```
$string = "https:\/\/s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/dev-lopes\/videos\/585903773a9_654641765275736"
```

My intention is to have the videos path (stripping the escaped forward slash) and the identifier set to a variable, like `videos/585903773a9_654641765275736`

Is this possible using str_replace or is this strictly regex required?

Comment: Why are the forward slashes in yout literal PHP string being escaped?

Answer (score -1):

**Try this Way. I think it will help you. I hope you will get your desire output.**

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$string = "https:\/\/s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com\/dev-lopes\/videos\/585903773a9_654641765275736";

//remove back slashes
$str1 = stripslashes($string);

//count total string length.
$len = strlen($str1);
//pick the position of /videos
$pos = strpos($str1,'/vid');

//split it from the url.
$break_string = substr($str1, $pos, $len);

//output: /videos/585903773a9_654641765275736
echo($break_string);
?>
```